# How to pass model values from a view to a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, view, controller, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode in Mac creating a MVC.

The parameter "new { problem = @Model }" shouldn't pass the values from the view to the controller?

View code:

```
@model ProblemsV4.Models.ProblemModel

<h2>New Solution</h2>

@using(Html.BeginForm("SaveSolution", "Problem", new { problem = @Model }, FormMethod.Get))
{
    <label>Solution: </label>
    <input type="text" name="solution" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
}
```

Controller code:

```
public IActionResult SaveSolution(ProblemModel problemModel, string solution)
        {
            SolutionModel model = new SolutionModel();

            model.Solution = solution;

            ProblemBC bc = new ProblemBC();

            bc.AddSolution(model);

            List<ProblemModel> models = bc.ListAll();
            ViewBag.Message = "Solução inserida com sucesso";

            return View("Index", models);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should receive a `HttpPost` at the controller and send the parameters of the model with a `HiddenFor`, a type of
`HtmlHelper` that doesn't shows any input.

The BeginForm method has many signatures, one of them contains the Object routeValues, that is an object that contains the parameters for a route. You don't need to use that, 
you can use other signature like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460344(v=vs.118).aspx

**First step:**

```
[HttpPost] 
public IActionResult SaveSolution(ProblemModel problemModel, string solution) 
{ 
    SolutionModel model = new SolutionModel(); 

    model.Solution = solution; 

    ProblemBC bc = new ProblemBC(); 

    bc.AddSolution(model); 

    List<ProblemModel> models = bc.ListAll(); 

    ViewBag.Message = "Solução inserida com sucesso"; 

    return View("Index", models); 
}
```

**Second step:**

```
@model ProblemsV4.Models.ProblemModel 

<h2>New Solution</h2> 

@using(Html.BeginForm("SaveSolution", "Problem", FormMethod.Post)) 
{ 

    <label>Solution: </label> 

    <input type="text" name="solution" /><br/><br/> 

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Problem) 
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Description) 
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID) 

    <input type="submit" value="Save"/> 

}
```

Comment: Remove the `new{ problem = @Model.Problem }`, `new{ description = @Model.Description }` etc - that is adding invalid html attributes!